# Regular Expression for at least one character and one number

Tags: jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want a regex in which user have to type at least one character and one number in password field.

Right now I'm using using this:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
```

but it is not working properly.

Please help.

Comment: password can contains special character as well. there can be other character between digit and letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Try this expression

```
^\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

- Zero or more digits;
- One alpha character;
- Zero or more alphanumeric characters.

Try a few tests and you'll see this'll pass any alphanumeric string where at least one non-numeric character is required.

Comment: will it handle special character as well.

Comment: This doesn't match a password like "1_foo" unlike mine.

Answer (score 1):

use below regex:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nn92H/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 ^.*(?=.{1,10})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// at least one number, one character
// at least six characters
var re = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*)(?=.*).{6,}/;
return re.test(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will identify a number followed by a letter, or a letter followed by a number, with any number of non-numeric/alpha characters in between them.

```
/([0-9].*[a-zA-Z])|([a-zA-Z].*[0-9])/
```

Answer (score 0):

This'll work:

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]) //with 'i' flag
```

[Demo Here](http://regex101.com/r/cT2kS1/1)

[This Page](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=password&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) contains many *password regex*. go through it!